# Plotting images while removing any that have overlap on the pixel level

Tags: r, ggplot2

So I have this really basic example of using `geom_image`. What I would like to achieve is to not plot those images which will have overlap in the graphic based on overlap in pixels between two images or more. Is there some way to perform this?

Is there maybe a way of converting said images into boxes or shapes and first see if there will be any overlap?

See my basic plot below:

```r
library("ggplot2")
library("ggimage")

# create a df

set.seed(2017-02-21)
d <- data.frame(x = rnorm(10),
                y = rnorm(10),
                image = sample(c("https://www.r-project.org/logo/Rlogo.png",
                                 "https://jeroenooms.github.io/images/frink.png"),
                               size=10, replace = TRUE)
)
# plot2
ggplot(d, aes(x, y)) + geom_image(aes(image=image), size=.08)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-03-17 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: From looking at the docs and source code for `ggimage`, it seems there isn't an easy way to do this. There is a mechanism I can think of to achieve it, but it would involve writing a new geom inheriting from `geom_image`, with a new `draw_panel` function that incorporated collision detection. This would be beyond a typical SO question, though there are one or two folks round here who _might_ attempt it, or know of an alternative workaround.